# How do I find the minimum time for computing a trajecotry for a robotic arm?

Tags: robotic-arm, manipulator, trajectory

I am studying robotics and I am focusing on trajectory planning.

I have been struggling with this topic for a while, and I still have some doubts that I cannot solve. One of them is the following:

I was solving a problem for training which required this:

> **A robot joint should perform a rest-to-rest rotation $\Delta \theta $ in a total time $T$ by using a bang-coast-bang
>   acceleration profile with symmetric acceleration and deceleration phases, each of duration $Ts = \frac{T}{4}$.
>   Given a maximum joint velocity $V_{max} > 0$ and a maximum bound $A_{max} > 0$ for the absolute value of the
>   joint acceleration, find the minimum time $T_{min}$ in this class of trajectories such that the motion is feasible.**

I think that for let understand my doubts, I have to first say how I thought to tackle the problem, even if it is clearly the wrong way.

My idea for solving this proble was to find the maximum velocity, which is:

$V_{max}=\frac{T}{4}$

and from it derive the time $T$, which in my opinion was the minimum motion of time because it is referred to the maximum velocity. So, I thought the minumum time velocity to be:

$T = \frac{4V_{max}}{A}$

but this is obviusly wrong. Infact, when I went looking for the **solution** that my professor proposed for this exercise, the correct way was the following:

[image]

[image]

where there are also numercal values for the quantities, which I did not included in the question.

After seeing the solution, most concept where clarified. For example, I have understood that I should have calculated the minimum motion time for completing the otion(so for completing the total displacement) on the displacement from zero to $T$.

But there is still something I don't understand. In the solution, my professor derived a velocity $V$ and a displacement $\Delta \theta _s$ where this displacement is the displacement from zero to $\frac{T}{4}$ and it is equal to the displacement from $\frac{3T}{4}$ to $T$.

So, with this quantities he has computed the total displacement as :

$\Delta \theta = 2\Delta \theta _s+V\frac{T}{2}$

and from it he computed the acceleration and the velocity. Then he substitute in these the limit velocity and acceleration and then computed the minimum time trajectory.

But **why he needed to compute both acceleration and velocity form the total displacement?**

And **what is $V=\frac{T}{4}$ that he computed in the beginning? Shoudn't this be the maximum velocity?**

I have a lot of doubts on this, sice I do not understand also **what are  $A=\frac{16\Delta \theta }{3T^{2}}$ and $V=\frac{4\Delta \theta }{3T}$**

And also, **why there is the need to compute the time both from the acceleration and form the velocity?**

Can somebody please help me understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem statement is:

> using a bang-coast-bang acceleration profile with symmetric acceleration and deceleration phases, each of duration $T_s=\frac{T}{4}$.

So, right off, you know the **time spent** in acceleration is $T/4$. The peak velocity is *not* $T/4$.

I'll agree that your professor's notation is hard to read (for me at least), but it looks like they're using *functions* for the notation.

The "bang-coast-bang" is also called a trapezoidal speed profile and it's super common with my industry's speed-regulated motors.

So, if your speed $\dot{\theta}$ is a *function of time*, and you ramp up to full speed $V$ at time $t=T/4$, then you can express that data point by showing your speed, as a function of time $\dot{\theta}\left(t\right)$:

$$
\dot{\theta}\left(\frac{T}{4}\right) = V \\
$$

This might be more useful if you replace $V$ with $\dot{\theta}_{max}$:

$$
\dot{\theta}\left(\frac{T}{4}\right) = \dot{\theta}_{max} \\
$$

and again, it's just saying that your angular speed $\dot{\theta}$ reaches your maximum speed at $t = \frac{T}{4}$. Remember that "big T", $T$, is the *total time elapsed for the move*, or the *period* for this operation.

Now, the other way you can express a speed, generically speaking, is:

$$
v = \int\left(a\right)dt \\
$$

which, for a constant acceleration, is:

$$
v = at \\
$$

Speed is acceleration times time. If you are using a constant acceleration, then you could *also* say that

$$
\dot{\theta}\left(t=\frac{T}{4}\right) = A\frac{T}{4} \\
$$

So now put those two statements above together and see that:

$$
\boxed{\dot{\theta}\left(\frac{T}{4}\right) = V = A\frac{T}{4}} \\
$$

This is a slight re-arranging of your professor's statement $
V = \dot{\theta}\left(\frac{T}{4}\right) = A\frac{T}{4} \\
$, but I find the professor's form more confusing because then it looks like $V$ is a function of $\dot{\theta}(t)$ and not the other way around.

The next line goes on to continue the "classic" constant-acceleration position formula:

$$
x(t) = x_0 + v_0 t + \frac{1}{2}at^2 \\
$$

or, in your angular case:

$$
\theta(t) = \theta_0 + \dot{\theta}_0 t + \frac{1}{2} A t^2 \\
$$

And here you can move your $\theta_0$ and assume  $\dot{\theta}_0 = 0$ and so you wind up with:

$$
\theta(t) - \theta_0 = \frac{1}{2}A t^2 \\
$$

and, since $\theta(t) - \theta_0 = \Delta \theta(t)$, you can re-write *that* as:

$$
\Delta \theta(t) = \frac{1}{2}A t^2 \\
$$

Now again you're trying to find out how much the angle shifted at the end of the starting acceleration period $(\Delta \theta_s)$, and the acceleration period ends at $t = \frac{T}{4}$, so:

$$
\boxed{
\Delta \theta_s = \Delta\theta\left(t = \frac{T}{4}\right) = \frac{1}{2}A\left(\frac{T}{4}\right)^2} \\
$$

And now, finally, your speed profile states you accelerate for $t = \frac{T}{4}$, you move at constant speed $V$ for $t = \frac{T}{2}$, and you decelerate for $t = \frac{T}{4}$. Since your acceleration and deceleration rates are the same, the total angle traversed during that transient is the same and so:

$$
\Delta \theta\left(t = T\right) = \Delta \theta_s + V\frac{T}{2} + \Delta \theta_s \\
$$

Or, as your professor stated it,

$$
\boxed{\Delta \theta\left(t = T\right) = 2\Delta \theta_s + V\frac{T}{2}} \\
$$

---

So, what is $V$? That's from the first boxed equation here:

$$
\dot{\theta}\left(\frac{T}{4}\right) = V = A\frac{T}{4} \\
$$

and you can see:

$$
V = A\frac{T}{4} \\
$$

And, what is $\Delta \theta_s$? From the second boxed equation:

$$
\Delta \theta_s = \Delta\theta\left(t = \frac{T}{4}\right) = \frac{1}{2}A\left(\frac{T}{4}\right)^2 \\
$$

so:

$$
\Delta \theta_s = \frac{1}{2}A\left(\frac{T}{4}\right)^2 \\
$$

And finally you can plug that all into the third boxed equation:

$$
\Delta \theta\left(t = T\right) = 2\Delta \theta_s + V\frac{T}{2} \\
$$

And get:

$$
\Delta \theta\left(t = T\right) = 2\left(\frac{1}{2}A\left(\frac{T}{4}\right)^2\right) + \left(A\frac{T}{4}\right)\frac{T}{2} \\
\Delta \theta\left(T\right) = \left(A\left(\frac{T}{4}\right)^2\right) + \left(A\frac{T}{4}\right)\frac{T}{2} \\
\Delta \theta\left(T\right) = A\left(\frac{T}{4}\right)\left(\frac{T}{4}\right) + A\left(\frac{T}{4}\right)\left(\frac{T}{2}\right) \\
\Delta \theta\left(T\right) = A\left(\frac{T^2}{16}\right) + A\left(\frac{T^2}{8}\right) \\
\Delta \theta\left(T\right) = A\left(\frac{T^2}{16}\right) + A\left(\frac{2T^2}{16}\right) \\
\boxed{\Delta \theta\left(T\right) = A\left(\frac{3T^2}{16}\right)}\\
$$

And, realizing that the total angle change $\Delta\theta$ **is defined to be** $\Delta\theta(T)$, you can solve the boxed equation on the line above as:

$$
\Delta \theta = A\left(\frac{3T^2}{16}\right)\\
\Delta \theta\frac{16}{3T^2} = A \\
\boxed{A = \frac{16\Delta\theta}{3T^2}} \\
$$

You can solve for $V$ the same way with your expression $V = A\frac{T}{4}$, solving for $A = V\frac{4}{T}$, and then substituting into the above boxed formula:

$$
A = V\frac{4}{T} = \frac{16\Delta\theta}{3T^2} \\
\boxed{V = \frac{4\Delta\theta}{3T}} \\
$$

Hope this helps!